# Объясните принцип разработки TDD

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

Нашел такое задание в курсе по C#:

**Implement Vending machine in code using TDD approach**

There are following features:

- You can update product list at any time
- You can insert coins, get coins back and get remainder
- You can buy 1 product at once for inserted coins
- Machine accepts following coins: 5ȼ, 10ȼ, 20ȼ, 50ȼ, 1 € and 2 €

Есть такой интерфейс:

```
  public interface IVendingMachine
  {
    /// <summary>Vending machine manufacturer.</summary> 
    string Manufacturer { get; }

    /// <summary>Amount of money inserted into vending machine. </summary> 
    Money Amount { get; }

    /// <summary>Products that are sold.</summary> 
    Product[] Products { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Inserts the coin into vending machine.</summary> 
    /// <param name="amount">Coin amount.</param>
    Money InsertCoin(Money amount);

    /// <summary>Returns all inserted coins back to user.</summary> 
    Money ReturnMoney();

    /// <summary>Buys product from list of product.</summary> 
    /// <param name="productNumber">Product number in vending machine product list.</param>
    Product Buy(int productNumber);
  }

  public struct Money
  {
    public int Euros { get; set; }
    public int Cents { get; set; }
  }

  public struct Product
  {
    /// <summary>Gets orsets the available amount of product.</summary> 
    public int Available { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets orsetsthe product price.</summary> 
    public Money Price { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets orsetsthe product name.</summary> 
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

Как будет выглядеть разработка от тестов?
Насколько я понял сначала нужно реализовать тест метода а потом его написать, но не понимаю как можно написать сначала юнит-тест, а потом реализовать метод.
Раньше не писал никогда юниты, можете помочь объяснить и показать на примере?

Answer (score 4):

Хорошее задание.

Главное - у вас есть предметная область, а именно - то что надо уметь выполнять (требования и возможности сущности).

В вашем случае - начинаем с создания класса, реализующего интерфейс. Пока пустого:

```
  public class VendingMachine : IVendingMachine
  {
    public Money Amount { get; }
    public Product[] Products { get; set; }
    public Money InsertCoin(Money amount)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Money ReturnMoney()
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Product Buy(int productNumber)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Manufacturer { get; }
  }
```

---

**Первое требование - You can update product list at any time**

Интерфейс не имплементирует, как именно это будет происходить, а потому главный вопрос к TDD - как именно стороннему разработчику будет удобно обновлять ассортимент.

Пишем тест на это дело:

```
  var machine = new VendingMachine();
  machine.AddProduct();
```

Сразу задумываемся, а как же удобно рулить продуктами, ведь судя по структуре продукта, в ней же задается количество\название и цена экземпляра.
Я предпочту простой вариант:

```
  var beerPrice = new Money() {Euros = 1, Cents = 10 };
  machine.AddOrUpdateProduct("Пиво", beerPrice, 3);
```

Сразу добавим метод с такой сигнатурой в класс:

```
public void AddOrUpdateProduct(string name, Money beerPrice, int count)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Теперь дописываем тест для того, чтобы он проверял необходимый нам кейс:

```
  var machine = new VendingMachine();
  var beerPrice = new Money() {Euros = 1, Cents = 10 };
  var count = 3;
  machine.AddOrUpdateProduct("Пиво", beerPrice, count);

  Assert.AreEqual(machine.Products.Length, 1);
  Assert.AreEqual(machine.Products[0].Available, count);
```

Запускаем тест - получаем ошибку:

> Метод проверки TDD.UnitTest1.UpdateVendingMachineProducts выдал
>   исключение:  System.NotImplementedException: Метод или операция не
>   реализована..

Сложная часть работы завершена, осталось реализовать простой способ, который поднимет тест. Простой, но действующий так, будто сущность существует в реальном мире, не стоит городить магию.

Работать с массивами я лично не люблю, поэтому спрячу в реализации список, в итоге:

```
public Product[] Products
{
  get { return products.ToArray(); }
  set { products = value.ToList(); }
}

private List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

public void AddOrUpdateProduct(string name, Money beerPrice, int count)
{
  products.Add(new Product() {Available = count, Name = name, Price = beerPrice});
}
```

Тест успешно прошел, первая фича реализована, ура.

---

**Вторая - You can insert coins, get coins back and get remainder**

Описание дает элементарный намек на три теста - вставил денег, вернул, получил сдачу.
Первые два реализовать можно прямо сейчас, третий - лучше отложить, сдача может быть только от покупки, а про неё пока ни слова.
Тут нам интерфейс задан вполне неплохо, пишем тесты по нему:

```
[TestMethod]
public void InsertCoin()
{
  var machine = new VendingMachine();
  var inserted = new Money() {Euros = 1};
  var returned = machine.InsertCoin(inserted);
  Assert.AreEqual(machine.Amount, inserted);
  Assert.AreEqual(returned, inserted);
}

[TestMethod]
public void ReturnMoney()
{
  var machine = new VendingMachine();
  var count = 1;
  machine.InsertCoin(new Money() { Euros = count });
  var back = machine.ReturnMoney();

  Assert.AreEqual(back.Euros, count);
  Assert.AreEqual(machine.Amount.Euros, 0);
}
```

Реализуем:

Деньги перегрузим, пусть сами складываются. Пока элементарно:

```
public static Money operator +(Money m1, Money m2)
{
  return new Money() { Euros = m1.Euros + m2.Euros, Cents = m1.Cents + m2.Cents };
}
```

Итого, для первого теста:

```
public Money Amount { get; protected set; }

public Money InsertCoin(Money amount)
{
  Amount = Amount + amount;
  return Amount;
}
```

И для второго:

```
public Money ReturnMoney()
{
  var amount = Amount;
  Amount = new Money();
  return amount;
}
```

Не забываем про предметную часть - сумма в автомате должна меняться при этих операциях.
Ура, у нас три зеленых теста.

---

**Третий случай - You can buy 1 product at once for inserted coins**

Если я правильно понял, можно купить только один продукт за раз. После этого сдача вернётся. Не пользовался автоматами, если ошибся - ну извините.

Тест меня сразу обломал - интерфейс ввода для пользователя - цифровой!
Будем считать, что цифры от 1. Пишем тест:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Buy()
{
  var machine = new VendingMachine();
  var beerPrice = new Money() { Euros = 1, Cents = 10 };
  var count = 3;
  var name = "Пиво";
  machine.InsertCoin(new Money() { Euros = count });
  machine.AddOrUpdateProduct(name, beerPrice, count);
  var product = machine.Buy(1);

  Assert.AreEqual(machine.Products[0].Available, count - 1);
  Assert.AreEqual(product.Name, name);
  Assert.AreEqual(machine.Amount, default(Money));
}
```

Фух, снаружи простой тест вызывает кучу вопросов. Деньги проще сделать хотя бы частично работающими с простыми операциями:

```
public static Money operator +(Money m1, Money m2)
{
  return new Money() { Euros = m1.Euros + m2.Euros, Cents = m1.Cents + m2.Cents };
}

public static Money operator -(Money m1, Money m2)
{
  return new Money() { Euros = m1.Euros - m2.Euros, Cents = m1.Cents - m2.Cents };
}

public static bool operator <(Money m1, Money m2)
{
  if (m1.Euros != m2.Euros)
    return m1.Euros < m2.Euros;

  return m1.Cents < m2.Cents;
}

public static bool operator >(Money m1, Money m2)
{
  return m2 < m1;
}

public static bool operator ==(Money m1, Money m2)
{
  return m1.Euros == m2.Euros && m1.Cents == m2.Cents;
}

public static bool operator !=(Money m1, Money m2)
{
  return !(m1 == m2);
}
```

Продукту это тоже не помешает:

```
public static Product operator +(Product m1, int m2)
{
  return new Product() { Available = m1.Available + m2, Price = m1.Price, Name = m1.Name };
}

public static Product operator -(Product m1, int m2)
{
  return new Product() { Available = m1.Available - m2, Price = m1.Price, Name = m1.Name };
}
```

Тогда, покупка выглядит более-менее простой, я правда так и не понял, какой товар вернуть должен интерфейс - я возвращаю остаток в автомате, чтобы его можно было отобразить например.

```
public Product Buy(int productNumber)
{
  if (products.Count < productNumber || productNumber < 1)
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Товара нет.");

  var index = productNumber - 1;
  var product = products[index];
  if (product.Available <= 0)
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Товара нет.");

  if (Amount < product.Price)
    throw new Exception("Не хватает денег.");

  Amount = Amount - product.Price;
  ReturnMoney();

  product = product - 1;
  products[index] = product;

  return product;
}
```

Итак, третий тест теперь тоже зеленый.
Если вы думаете, что код пишется легко - я вас уверяю, быстрый запуск теста позволяет писать его ещё легче. Все исключения в методе Buy написаны исключительно благодаря тесту, но даже так какие то кейсы я мог пропустить.

---

Я не буду описывать последний кейс - в нём вся соль тестов.
Надо написать тест, добавить ограничения и словить боль от падения предыдущих тестов, которые работали с покупкой и кривыми введенными данными.
В этом вся соль TDD - вы написали себе логику прикладного разработчика, потом реализовали какую то внутреннюю и сложную хрень, а потом получили ту самую боль, которую испытывают все, кто пользуется вашей разработкой. Ваши страдания намного дешевле страданий пользователей, а потому TDD(который и PainDD вполне) и помогает писать тесты и стабильный продукт.

Запускайте тест чаще при разработке - он сразу скажет, что вы забыли.
При разработке методов - не забывайте проверять входные данные и данные окружающего мира, а то в тестах всегда есть желание дать невалидные данные и получить результат. Купить товар, не введя денег, запросить деньги, не добавляя их и прочее прочее. Чем больше у вас реальных кейсов поведения - тем конкретнее и полезнее будут ваши тесты, не стоит придумывать ерунды на тестирование.

UPD: куча вещей пропущена и по причине того, что не нужны для тестов и по причине лени. Центы не складываются в евро, товар можно только добавить, хотя на деле нужно бы количественное добавление, цену товара нельзя поменять. Над чем то надо думать, что то уточнять у бизнес-аналитика или специалиста по предметной области - сложностей хватает.

Answer (score 1):

1. Понимание того что хотите создать. В общих чертах это представить
2. Написать тест, как будто объект тестирования уже написан
3. ***Запустить тест***. Убедиться что тест упал. Это важно!
4. Написать код в объекте тестирования код достаточный, чтобы скомпилировалось
5. ***Запустить тест***. Убедиться что тест пройден. Это важно!
6. Написать код в объекте тестирования
7. ***Запустить тест***. Убедиться что тест пройден. Это важно!
8. Провести рефакторинг, если нужно
9. ***Запустить тест***. Убедиться что тест пройден. Это важно!

Нельзя пренебрегать запуском теста между этами разработки. Тест **обязан** падать  там, где нужно упасть. Именно по этой причине п.3, п.5, п.7 и п.9 крайне важны!

После того как объект тестирования реализован нужно убедиться, что тест:

- Находится в правильном наборе тестирования. Если это не так, то перенести куда следует;
- Содержит только и только одну проверку. Должна быть только и только одна причина по которой тест должен упасть. Другими словами должен быть только и только один `assert`. Если не получается, то воспользуйтесь библиотекой типа `hamcrest`;
- Выполняется достаточно быстро. Основное качество модульного теста это скорость работы. Если модульные тесты будут работать медленно, разработчик будет избегать их запуска.

Comment: Одна проверка `assert` на тест — это настоятельная рекомендация, а не догматичное требование. Такое ограничение делает тесты более понятными, но я не считаю несколько директив `assert` в тесте преступлением, если тест в целом делает _одну_ проверку и остаётся чистым.

Comment: @ИльдарХайруллин: Вы ошибаетесь. Это не рекомендация. Это требование! В тесте не может быть больше чем одно утвеждение! assert это "утверждаю". Тест может быть осуществлен только с помощью проверки утверждений относительно чего-либо. Если тест провален, а в нем несколько утверждений, то как ответить на вопрос: "А что конкретно сломалось?". Другими словами программист обязан будет открыть код теста и посмотреть утверждения. А зачем? Вы можете сказать, что должен быть подробный отчет в котором есть стэекдампы. Но зачем его включать?

Comment: Как узнать, где именно сбой? Элементарно: при срабатывании `assert` выдаёт диагностическую строку. Не все идеологи TDD считают это требованием к, примеру, Кент Бек и Роберт Мартин.

Comment: Соглашусь с @ИльдарХайруллин: под одной проверкой подразумевается один тест-кейс. Каждый тест должен проверять только один тест-кейс. Иногда для проверки тест-кейса нужно несколько вызовов `Assert.Xxx()`, это нормально. Различать их можно и нужно, вписывая в каждый адекватное сообщение об ошибке. Что не нужно делать -- проверять в одном тесте *несколько* тест-кейсов.

Comment: @andreycha: Не согласен. Один тест - один `assert`! Перевод этого слова на русский "Утверждаю". Мы не можем проверять несколько утверждений в одном тесте! `assert` конструкция проверяет 1 предположение относительно объекта тестирования, а тест проверяет ровно одно предположение, иначе это уже тесты! Мы не можем сами по себе тесты написать, поэтому мы оформляем их в виде функций. Они не могут сами по себе работать и поэтому мы используем вызовы `assert`. Программист НЕ должен заглядывать в лог, чтобы уточнить что именно сломалось, он должен из названия теста это понимать причину поломки

Comment: @sys_dev попахивает фанатизмом. Вот посмотрите, даже гуру юнит-тестирования Рой Ошеров более мягок в этом вопросе: "My guideline is usually that you test one logical CONCEPT per test. you can have multiple asserts on the same *object*. they will usually be the same concept being tested." [(с)](http://www.owenpellegrin.com/blog/testing/how-do-you-solve-multiple-asserts/comment-page-1/#comment-6469)

Comment: А вы просто скажите, как проверить что на операцию и выпал товар из автомата и сдача? Два разных теста, отличающихся одной строкой - assertом? По моему - глупость.

Comment: @Monk: Элементарно! Создать 2 теста! Один теста позволяющий проверку выдачи товара, а второй тест проверяющий выдачу сдачи. Назовем операцию при которой выпадает товар , а также выпадает сдача - операция1. Пишем тест1. В нем выполняется операция1 и проверка на то что выпал товар. Пешем тест2 в нем выполняется таже самая операция1 и за ней следует проверка на то что выдана сдача. Итого: признак двух тестов это когда нужно написать 2 `assert`-а

Comment: А теперь представим, что время работы теста - 20 минут. Вы только что взяли и удвоили его, сэкономив какой то `assert`. Да, я понимаю что тут тесты дешевые. В реальной жизни - тесты бывают намного сложнее и дороже.

Comment: @Monk: "время работы теста - 20 минут" Ошибка! При TDD применяются модульные тесты(unit tests). Основное качество модульного теста скорость его работы. Даже пол-минуты очень много! А 20 минут, за такое программиста нужно отправить рефакторить и подумать головой еще раз. Если это 20 минут это друго тип теста, возможно интеграционный, может еще какой,  но не модульный!

Comment: Т.е. TDD нельзя применять к тестам, которые долго выполняются? Категорически?

Comment: @Monk: Именно! Категорически нельзя! В TDD применяются исключительно модульные тесты. Модульный тест это помошник и лучший друг для разработчика. Разработчик должен СЕЙЧАС понять, где он внес ошибку, а не через 1-2 дня или 2 недели после отпуска, когда он уже и забыл как все работает. Он сейчас внес правку, запустил модульные тесты и чем быстрее они ему скажут, где он сделал ошибку тем быстрее он исправит ее. А теперь спросите себя как программиста : Возрастет ли ваше желание запускать набор тестов для компонента если он работает не 5 минут, а 1 минуту?

Comment: Я хочу знать хотя бы сегодня же, а не сломал ли я своим мелким исправлением поведение сотни другой юзер-кейсов. В остальном - не спешу. И вполне пишу TDD. Вот никогда не задумывался, что время как то влияет на используемый подход.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45914/discussion-between-sys-dev-and-monk).

Comment: @sys_dev пример с выдачей продукта и сдачей -- не совсем корректный. Тут действительно нужны два отдельных теста. А вот, например, как одним ассертом проверить, что метод вернул список, состоящий из одного определенного элемента?

Comment: @andreycha: Если для бизнеса важно чтобы именно из одного элемента И конкретного типа, то почему это не отдельная сущность в production коде? С другой стороны можно написать `match` объект, про библиотеку `hamcrest` я уже упоминал в своем комментарии

Answer (score 0):

> Насколько я понял сначала нужно реализовать тест метода а потом его
>   написать

Абсолютно верно. В этом и заключается основная идея разработки через тестирования (TDD). Определив интерфейс функции или класса, далее ты определяешь набор требований к функционалу через соответствие входных и выходных данных. Например тебе нужно реализовать поиск большего из 2х чисел (пример на С++, но смысл должен быть понятен)

```
template<typename T>
T max(const T& a, const T& b);

Условный набор тестов:
assert(max(1, 4) == 4);
assert(max(4, 1) == 4);
assert(max(-1, -4) == -1);
```

После этого ты начинаешь реализовывать метод и в конечном счете все тесты должны пройти. Аналогично с классом терминала продаж определив интерфейс пишешь тесты на то, как изменится внутреннее представление экземпляра класса при вызове его методов с разными параметрами

Comment: Чуточку не так. _Сначала_ вырабатываются требования к программе/модулю/классу/методу, после этого они пишутся на языке тестов. В процессе составления требований и кодирования их в тестах можно составить приемлемый на данный момент интерфейс.

Answer (score -1):

> не понимаю как можно написать сначала юнит-тест, а потом реализовать метод

Это нормально. Этого никто не понимает. Не зная предметную область, не обсудив ТЗ с заказчиком и с коллегами, не имея большого опыта разработки в целом и опыта разработки в данной предметной области в частности, *невозможно* сразу начать писать тесты.

Те, кто уверяют, что нужно сразу писать *красный* тест, слегка лукавят. Сколько я ни общался с такими разработчиками, сколько ни видел примеров в интернете, там *всегда* пишется тест на *уже знакомую* тему. То есть данный разработчик участвовал по крайней мере в одном проекте (а скорее в нескольких на протяжении ряда лет) в данной предметной области. И вот на основании своего предыдущего многолетнего опыта он и способен написать *сперва* тест. Но на самом деле, сперва был написан *код*: в *предыдущих* проектах.

А как дело касается новой предметной области, опять начинается написание сперва пробных кусков кода, их переписывание, выбрасывание... Писать тест на код, который гарантированно будет выброшен, нет смысла. И лишь после нескольких итераций выкристаллизовывается некий каркас, по которому можно начинать писать тесты.

Поэтому, не расстраивайтесь, когда у вас не будет сразу получаться писать *сперва тесты* и лишь потом код.

Comment: На самом деле, это не совсем нормально. TDD позволяет минимизировать проектирование, но не выработку требований. Тесты основываются на требованиях. По сути, тесты — это и есть требования в цифровой форме. Тест как декларация того, _что_ должен делать метод, тело метода — реализация, _как_ он будет это делать.

Comment: @ИльдарХайруллин поспорю. Тесты должны проверять *контракт* -- пары вход-выход. То, что находится между входом и выходом, т.е. реализацию, они не должны проверять. Иначе мы рискуем получить слишком хрупкие тесты -- реализация имеет свойство меняться чаще, чем контракт. Тесты должны проверять "что", но не "как".

Comment: @andreycha, именно это я и имел в виду («тест как декларация _что_ должен делать метод»). Тест ожидает от тестируемого метода определённого результата в соответствии с требованиями. Про привязку теста к реализации я ничего не говорил — наверное, просто неясно выразился.

Comment: @ИльдарХайруллин перечитал ваш комментарий еще раз и понял, что я вас не так понял :). Прошу прощения. Все верно говорите.